# Reset ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using some fancy WPF-based UI framework that defines ControlTemplates for all the basic controls. So if I have a ListBox, it is styled according to the theme of this framework.

I'd like to use a single ListBox that has a completely different style, and so I'd like to disable the ControlTemplate *for this particular control only* and build up a style from scratch.

I've tried setting the Template property to null on this control, as shown below, but it didn't work:

```
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}" />
```

How can I reset the ControlTemplate for this control in order to get rid of the framework-specific styles and weave my own?

Comment: <ListBox Style="{x:Null}"/>

Comment: I want to eliminate the ControlTemplate AND define a style of my own, not just clear the style.

Comment: The framework defines default styles without keys or custom controls (i.e. affects all of them)?

Comment: <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/> to override default template and style ................and to define new tempate <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                      ..
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

Comment: Edit the Style of the Control in Blend, change the Template to whatever you want.

Comment: @DanielWard yes, it defines default styles, and in these it sets the template as per the second part of Heena's comment above.

Comment: Can you just make a new WPF project without the framework, copy and paste the default template, and then work from there?

Answer (score 0):

No need to resort to styles and setters if you only want to change the template for this one control:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="20" Fill="Red"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```